# Inclution place of CSS file

Tags: css

From Network Tab of browser of my WordPress site, I found `style.css` file is included.I would like to remove this inclusion. How can I remove this inclusion ? Where did it include ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this function to 'functions.php' in theme directory to remove style.css while wordpress loading your styles.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_dequeue_style('put-your-sytle-css-handle-name');
});
```